# When adding image to canvas from an upload field it is selected but hidden behind the canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

The *input* variable in the function is the image send from and upload input file field.

```
    function readURLForSticker(input) {
TypeBelettering = "sticker";
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    
    var imgs = new Image();
    imgs.onload = function () {
      originalImageHeightPX = this.height;
      originalImageWidthPX = this.width;
      imageHeightMM = originalImageHeightPX * 0.2645833333;
      imageWidthMM = originalImageWidthPX * 0.2645833333;


    };
    imgs.onerror = function () {
      alert("not a valid file: " + file.type);
    };
    urlLogo = _URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);  
    imgs.src = urlLogo;
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      imgs.src = e.target.result;
      
      stickerImage = new fabric.Image(imgs);
      canvas.add(stickerImage);
      canvas.centerObject(stickerImage);
      canvas.setActiveObject(stickerImage);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    imageUploaded = true;
  }
  
}
```

This is what sent by the input

```
$("#upload-picture").change(function() {

  readURLForSticker(this);
        
});
```

The image works when you drag it a little bit but for dummy's it is not useabble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've provided appears to be incomplete so rather than try to create a working example out of it, here is a basic demo of how to add an image to a Fabric.js canvas using a file input.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

document.getElementById("uploader").onchange = function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = e.target.result;
    image.onload = function() {
      var img = new fabric.Image(image);
      img.set({
        left: 100,
        top: 100
      });
      img.scaleToWidth(200);
      canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img).renderAll();
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
<input id="uploader" type="file"/>
```

Comment: Omg thanks! does work now :D. But what did i forget? Because i cant find it, but still thanks for the comment!

Comment: There are few things...the `_URL` variable isn't defined and you've got some issues with scope and accessing resources before they've been loaded.